# Quirk in Python on multiple inheritance! At least I think so

Tags: python, inheritance

I have been working on a multiple inheritance code which looks similar to this:

```
class Document():
    def save(self, x):
        print "inside Document from " + x

class Cdm(object):
    def save(self,x):
        print "inside Cdm from " + x
        super(Cdm,self).save('Cdm')

class Contacts(Cdm, Document):
    def __init__(self):
        self.save('Contacts')
```

This is the result I get when I create an instance of Contacts.

```
> c = Contacts()
< inside Cdm from Contacts
< inside Document from Cdm
```

Now this is just weird, possibly to my eye. I might have misunderstood something. As you can see, the class Contacts inherits from cdm and Document. I am trying to use the save method of Cdm from Contacts. But Cdm inherits from object and does not have a super class method called save yet it calls the save function from Document class. In the program what I am working this is the behaviour I want but I am worried as theoretically it should not work or at least I think.

Do you have any comments on this. Or have I misunderstood Python's inheritance.

Comment: You are mixing old and new-style classes here. This is most certainly not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) says:

> super(): Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type.

In that situation, `super(Cdm,self).save('Cdm')` will call the version of `save()` which is next in method resolution order. In that case it is the `save()` method in the `Document` class because it is a sibling class of `Cdm` (i.e. it is the second base class of `Contacts`).

A great practical explanation of `super()` can be found here: [Python’s super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Answer (score 1):

`super(Cdm,self).save('Cdm')` calls the `save` method of the next class in the mro. This may not be a direct parent of the current class.

For more info about how super works and what it can be used for, you can refer to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) and [this blog post](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the answer.